Comparing the mapping regions of sky surveys - southern hemisphere in particular
I'm looking for information on the field of view of sky surveys, particularly in the southern hemisphere. The only ones I know of are DESI, WiggleZ and 6dF. I'd like to look specifically at their fields of view (RA and dec or galactic coords). Neither the Wikipedia page on astronomical survyes nor this pdf, which I got from this question help with this specific information.
Is there anywhere I can find such info?
